# How to add mathematical symbol with \hat and multiple clips in glossary?

Tags: errors, symbols, glossaries, clip

I want to add a `Symbol` in the `glossary` with this command:

```
\newglossaryentry{hU1}}{name={$\hat{u}_{1}$}, description={amplitude}, type=symbolslist, sort=amplitude}
```

The Error I get then:

```
Argument of \newglossaryentry has an axtra "}".
```

Without the "`\hat`"-part it works fine.
Does anyone have an idea how to fix it?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE...Can you provide the codes which are in executable format? (e.g, `\documentclass{...}\usepackage{...}\begin{document}...\end{document}`

Comment: This may be too simplistic, but the definition you show starts with `\newglossaryentry{hU1}}`.  That looks like one too many `}`.